# Java Scanner thread "main" exception error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculator

I have been working on a basic calculator in Java (Eclipse) and ran into some trouble displaying anything after the top two strings besides:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Commands.main(Commands.java:29)
```

I'm pretty sure I'm creating the Scanner and returning the values correctly, so I have no idea what's going on...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Commands {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double num1;
        double num2;
        String operation;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter the first number:");
            num1 = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please enter the second number:");
            num2 = input.nextInt();
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the error message it appears you try to call `next()` after you've closed the `Scanner` object. Only close it once you are completely done using it

Comment: @GBlodgett thank you! That seemed to fix it.

Comment: Don't close the `Scanner` at all. You didn't open `System.in`, and closing the scanner will close it. The general rule of thumb is: don't close a stream that you didn't open. (If your IDE gives you a warning about a resource leak, it is safe to ignore/suppress it in this case).

Answer (score -1):

The code works well for me:

```
System.out.println(num1 + num2);
```

> Please enter the first number:
>   100
>   Please enter the second number:
>   200
>   300.0

[image: The code works well for me]

Comment: You should copy and paste your code, please don't paste the image here

Comment: I'm a new user and I don't know how to paste code. Can you show me, thanks?

Comment: Just copy your code from IDE, and paste in in your answer. Select your code and Command+K for indent your code (If you are using Windows, may be Ctrl+K)